# Aperiodic cube tilings in all dimensions $n\geq3$

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, tiling, tessellations

In a paper the following statement is made ([link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-103/issue-1/Orthonormal-bases-of-exponentials-for-the-n-cube/10.1215/S0012-7094-00-10312-2.full)):

*"We note that in high dimensions there are many "exotic" cube tilings. There are aperiodic cube tilings in all dimensions $n\geq3$, while in dimensions $n\geq10$ there are cube tilings in which no two cubes share a common $(n-1)$-face (Lagarias and Shor [8])"*

The last part is not relevant for the question, and the reference only verifies that part. The authors do not provide any reference for the claim *"There are aperiodic cube tilings in all dimensions $n\geq 3$ "*.

I have done some extensive searching and I cannot find any examples of this. There are many who constructs aperiodic tiles from the unit cube/n-cube/n-dimensional hypercube, but I have not found an example which uses an unmodified(!) version. In this context, especially considering the latter part of the sentence (which *only* is for unmodified cubes) "cube tilings" here must be of the unmodified type. Examples of modified ones are ones such as Ammann tiles, or the L tile by Chaim Goodman-Strauss.

Given that the unit cube is so important in mathematics, why is there no mention of such a tiling on even the [wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_aperiodic_sets_of_tiles#cite_note-Aperiodic_pair_of_tiles_in_En-76) of aperiodic tiles? And given that they have not referenced this, is this common knowledge? Or is it totally wrong since I can find no books/papers/drawings/evidence of this.

Comment: I would think you could just start with the usual periodic tiling (cubes at each lattice point in $\mathbb{Z}^n$), and then rotate each "layer" (where layer $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ consists of all the cubes with first coordinate equal to $i$) by a different amount.  This construction requires $n \ge 3$, of course.

Comment: @MishaLavrov this will still be periodic in the y axis

Comment: @caduk Oh, true. So this does require $n\ge 3$ to work. However, I still don't think that the rotated-layer construction counts as fully aperiodic, at least not by Wikipedia's definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aperiodic_tiling#Definition_and_illustration). (It depends of course on what the authors of the paper mean by an aperiodic cube tiling.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot provide a reference and I am not sure whether I read about it somewhere, but the following construction comes to mind.

Start with the usual regular tessellation of the 3-dimensional space by cubes.

Now,

1. every column of cubes of the form $(x,y,z)$ with fixed even $x,y$ and $z$ running over all integers is shifted in the vertical direction; we require the shifts to be different and aperiodic over $x,y$. (For example, we can shift the column $(x,y,z)$ by $0.1$ if the total number of 1 bits in the binary expansion for $|x|$ and $|y|$ is odd or by $0.2$ otherwise, in the Thue-Morse spirit.)
2. Every row of cubes of the form $(x,y,z)$ with fixed odd $x$, fixed even $z$, and $y$ running over all integers is shifted in the $y$ direction; again, the shifts are different and aperiodic over $x,z$.
3. Every row of cubes of the form $(x,y,z)$ with fixed odd $y$, fixed odd $z$, and $x$ running over all integers is shifted in the $x$ direction; the shifts are different and aperiodic over $y,z$.

All these rows and columns can be shifted independently. The resulting cubic tessellation is aperiodic in all direction. This apparently generalizes to higher dimensions but doesn't work in the plane.

Comment: I get some trouble with the number 1., do you not need a condition that you also need fixed even y? Otherwise you would shift the entire y,z plane for each even x, and that would result in that it is not possible to shift the row in the x direction in 3. without “colliding” into the shifted plane, or pushing it all together -> creating non-negligible volumes with measure not equal to zero, I.e  we wouldn’t have a tiling anymore

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, just worded it clumsily. [Fixed even $x,y$] and [$z$ all integers].

Comment: Ah, I see! When it comes to the aperiodic part, when shifting a row in x direction (3.), does it not become aperiodic with respect to all other planes other than the y,z plane (combined with one other move)? Ex: it’s the shift in the y direction (2.) combined with the shift in x direction (1.) that makes it aperiodic in the y,z plane. etc.
Or have I got this wrong

Comment: Well, shifting a single row is not enough to get aperiodicity anyway (as Wikipedia puts it, aperiodic tiling "does not contain arbitrarily large periodic parts"). Apart from that, I think you're generally right. However you already get aperiodicity in all directions with shifts on any 2 out of 3 directions.

Comment: I was a bit unclear in my comment; when doing 1. You say that we get that it’s aperiodic with respect to the x,y plane. However, when we are shifting in the vertical direction, and this move is perpendicular to the x,y plane, how can it become aperiodic? Informally, from the “perspective” of the plane there would be a grid pattern since the motion is up and down,  and not the sideways in both directions of the plane

Comment: Ah. No, I don't mean that shifts introduce aperiodicity in the $x,y$ plane (to be more precise, in every direction except for $z$) automatically; instead, I design the shifts so that they are aperiodic. I edited the answer to clarify this.

Comment: After becoming more wiser on the notion of "non-periodic" and "aperiodic", I believe this to be a non-periodic tiling of unit cubes. Unit cubes are not aperiodic since there will always exist a lattice tiling of unit cubes, and for a tile to be aperiodic it must exclusively tile non-periodically. [p. 520, Tilings and Patterns; Gruenbaum, Shephard]. Hence, not answering the question.
However, it could be that it is a misunderstanding in the paper, and that they mean non-periodic, (next comment)

Comment: but then since there are also non-periodic tilings for the cube in $d=2$, why is the statement not "non-periodic cube tilings $d\geq2$". Example of non-periodic cube tiling in d=2; shift one row or column. Another completely non-periodic example is shifting the $d$'th column/row of cubes by a value of $e^d$

Comment: The specific tiling that I described is definitely aperiodic. The cube does not constitute an aperiodic set of tiles for the reason given in your comment, but that doesn't prevent a specific tiling from being aperiodic (so this doesn't contradict the claim from the paper quoted in your question).

Comment: As for your examples for $d=2$, they are periodic in the direction of the shifts. Cf. caduk's reply to mjqxxxx's comment.

Comment: So by "aperiodic" in this case, it is absence of a period in all coordinates. This is a great example of the confusion with these terms @_@.

Comment: Is it possible you can point me in a direction where I can find a reference?

Comment: Well, the English Wikipedia page on aperiodic tilings gives the definition of an aperiodic tiling (referencing the book Aperiodic Order vol. 1). It is based on the definition of a non-periodic tiling, which is "one that is not fixed by any non-trivial translation" (so your and mjqxxxx's examples clearly don't satisfy this). Grünbaum & Shephard also must discuss all this.